# After allocating the enough resource in the memory parameter in PostgreSQL why SWAP memory is fully utilized.?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have one production server in which below are the resource provisioned.

```
RAM: -256 GB
CPU: -64
```

i have set the below configuration after the resource allocated in the postgresql.auto.conf file: -

```
shared_buffers = '74GB'
effective_cache_size = '150GB'
maintenance_work_mem = '10GB'
work_mem = '4GB'
max_worker_processes = '64'
```

max_locks_per_transaction = '512'

After allocating tha much resource still SWAP memory has fully used:-

```
[root@xx-xx-xx-xx data]# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            251           6           4          73         240         171
Swap:             7           7           0
```

Can anyone help me with this issue. Is i have set something wrong in the tunning parameter. Also, how we can check the query is taking all the RAM which i have set.

Comment: You are aware that a single connection can use multiples of `work_mem` in a single query, aren't you? So you're looking to allow 64*4*n GB for queries. Also - your operating system will use some swap whenever it feels like it is useful - this isn't down to PostgreSQL.